# Passing a variable to PhantomJS via exec

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, phantomjs, gruntjs

I'm getting started with Grunt and wanting to pass a variable to a PhantomJS script I'm running via exec. What I want to be able to do is pass a url in for the script to take the screen capture from. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Darren

**Grunt script**

```
exec('phantomjs screenshot.js',
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        // Handle output
    }
);
```

**screenshot.js**

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://google.com', function () {
    page.render('google.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Command-line arguments are accessible via module `require('system').args` (Module `System`). The first one is always the script name, which is then followed by the subsequent arguments

This script will enumerate all arguments and write out to console.

```
var args = require('system').args;
if (args.length === 1) {
    console.log('Try to pass some arguments when invoking this script!');
}
else {
    args.forEach(function(arg, i) {
        console.log(i + ': ' + arg);
    });
}
```

In your case, the solution is

**Grunt**

```
exec('phantomjs screenshot.js http://www.google.fr',
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        // Handle output
    }
);
```

**screenshot.js**

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var address = system.args[1];
page.open(address , function () {
    page.render('google.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is an easy way to pass and pick args that are applicable. Very flexible and easy to maintain.

---

Use like:

```
phantomjs tests/script.js --test-id=457 --log-dir=somedir/
```

OR

```
phantomjs tests/script.js --log-dir=somedir/ --test-id=457
```

OR

```
phantomjs tests/script.js --test-id=457 --log-dir=somedir/
```

OR

```
phantomjs tests/script.js --test-id=457
```

Script:

```
var system = require('system');
// process args
var args = system.args;

// these args will be processed
var argsApplicable = ['--test-id', '--log-dir'];
// populated with the valid args provided in availableArgs but like argsValid.test_id
var argsValid = {};

if (args.length === 1) {
  console.log('Try to pass some arguments when invoking this script!');
} else {
  args.forEach(function(arg, i) {
    // skip first arg which is script name
    if(i != 0) {
      var bits = arg.split('=');
      //console.log(i + ': ' + arg);
      if(bits.length !=2) {
        console.log('Arguement has wrong format: '+arg);
      }
      if(argsApplicable.indexOf(bits[0]) != -1) {
        var argVar = bits[0].replace(/\-/g, '_');
        argVar = argVar.replace(/__/, '');
        argsValid[argVar] = bits[1];
      }
    }
  });
}
// enable below to test args
//require('utils').dump(argsValid);
//phantom.exit();
```