# phantomJS - Pass Argument to the JS File

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Right now I'm using the following command to run `phantomJS`

```
exec('./phantomjs table.js',$op,$er);
```

#### table.js

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('table.php', function () {
    page.render('table.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

This serves the purpose. But now I'm required to work with a dynamic variable, namely `date`. So is it possible to pass a PHP or Javascript variable inside the `exec` command line so that I can use that variable inside `table.js`?

#### Update

I tried modifying my code according to a solution posted here [Passing a variable to PhantomJS via exec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752882/passing-a-variable-to-phantomjs-via-exec?lq=1)

```
exec('./phantomjs table.js http://www.yahoo.com',$op,$er);
```

#### table.js

```
var args = require('system').args;
var page = require('webpage').create();
var address = system.args[1];
    page.open(address, function () {
        page.render('table.png');
        phantom.exit();
    });
```

But this results in 2 problems:

- The whole process takes about 3-4 minutes to finish
- After that I get "Server Not Found" message

If I remove the modified code, everything works as expected.

#### More Debugging

Inside **table.js** I used this:

```
var args = require('system').args;
args.forEach(function(arg, i) {

    console.log(i+'::'+arg);

});

var page = require('webpage').create();
var address = 'http://www.gmail.com';
page.open(address, function () {
    page.render('github.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

On running this, my `$op` (from `exec` command) printout out this:

```
Array ( [0] => 0::table.js [1] => 1::http://www.yahoo.com )
```

So far so good. But as soon as I put the below code, the same problems are encountered

```
var args = require('system').args;

var page = require('webpage').create();
var address = system.args[1]; // <--- This line is creating problem, the culprit
page.open(address, function () {
    page.render('github.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Seems like that is not the correct syntax. Anything obvious that I'm unable to see?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752882/passing-a-variable-to-phantomjs-via-exec

Comment: I tried that. I don't know why but that makes the browser hang up

Comment: Along with getting a "Server Not Found" message after about 3-4 minutes. If I remove the argument related code, everything gets back to normal.

Comment: could you please add a call to console.log in order to check system.args[1] ?

Comment: And how would I view the output? Through Firebug Console?

Comment: yes, you're true, it's not easy. Better solution : Use a file system log with the fs module.

Comment: Let me look up the fs module. Not familiar with it.

Comment: really easy https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference-FileSystem

Comment: any news about this ?

Comment: Oh..almost forgot about updating this. I decided to go for an alternative. Posting the answer below

Comment: @asprin Did the amount of time it took for the script to actually execute diminish at all? Or did it stay around 3-4 minutes for you?

Comment: @Ethan It did decrease. Check out my answer below.

Comment: @asprin got it, thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, I found an alternative to the above problem. Instead of using

```
var address = system.args[1];
```

I'm doing it by following the below modification

```
var args = require('system').args;
var address = '';
args.forEach(function(arg, i) {

    if(i == 1)
    {
       address = arg;
    }

});

var page = require('webpage').create();    
page.open(address, function () { // <-- use that address variable from above
    page.render('github.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: I think that the down votes may come from the fact that you are iterating over an array, just to get element '1' from it.  The preferred way would be to do: `var address = args[1];`

Answer (score 31):

The problem with your code is a simple oversight.

You have already stored the args using

```
var args = require('system').args;
```

So when you need to reference them you only have to do:

```
var address = args[1];
```

The use of "system" is looking in a completely different array

Answer (score 4):

I had to do this and this answers pointed me to find my final answer however as some people expressed here my browser was crashing... I found the problem and solution and thought was worth sharing...

This will work perfectly fine if:

```
exec('phantomjs phdemo.js http://google.com', $o, $e); ?>

var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');
var address = system.args[1]; 
page.open(address, function () {
    page.render('output.pdf');
    phantom.exit();
 });
```

However if you want to pass more than une parameter in the url address for example  google.com?searchteext&date=today I found that the character '&' crashes the browser as it expects it as a different command

My solution was to use the same but instead of putting & I used @ sign so the url will look something like  google.com?searchteext@date=today

then at the other end I added a string replace

```
var address = address.replace(/@/gi,"&");
```

Then everything works perfectly fine.... There may be other ways of doing it but this worked perfectly for me

Comment: Thanks for the info on the ampersand (&). Saved me some hours of debugging.