# How to setup PhantomJS to output a url's text

Tags: ruby, phantomjs, sinatra

I followed [this tutorial](https://blog.openshift.com/screen-scraper-as-a-service/) and have images of websites being created.  What I want is it to output text of a website not an image.

The `config.ru` file looks like this:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'digest/md5'

class App < Sinatra::Base

  get '/' do
    return "to specifiy the rendered URL use \"?url=&lt;some url&gt;\"" unless params[:url]
    digest = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(params[:url])
    system(File.expand_path("~/app-root/data/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs"), File.expand_path("~/app-root/data/phantomjs/examples/rasterize.js"), params[:url], "public/#{digest}.png")
    digest
  end

end

run App
```

I found an example for outputting the content, here's the code, `content.js`:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
page.open('http://google.com', function () {
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

So there are two questions:

1. How do I print out the `page.content`?
2. How do I pass the `url` query string parameter to `content.js` file?

Answer (score 0):

To use `console.log` you need to write a special listener - see [onConsoleMessage](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html). There's something similar in order to see errors, by the way.

There's an example given from those docs:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg, lineNum, sourceId) {
  console.log('CONSOLE: ' + msg + ' (from line #' + lineNum + ' in "' + sourceId + '")');
};
```

To pass arguments to the phantom script, I searched for existing StackOverflow questions and found [phantomJS - Pass Argument to the JS File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16814997/phantomjs-pass-argument-to-the-js-file). It appears that the way to do so is to use command line arguments. See the [phantom docs on `args`](http://phantomjs.org/api/system/property/args.html) for more detail.

It seems like your `system` call is ok, but in the phantom script you'll need to use `args` to read the passed arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Max.  With the console.log, I'm trying to print the text content of a website to the browser.  In other words, when someone visits http://myurl.com/?url=google.com I want to see all the text that is on that site.