# I need to pass variables to javascript called from php exec command

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php file that calls phantomjs via the exec command.  The phantom.js file calls a url that needs to include variables.  I need to send these variables from php along with the exec command and have the variables show up in the phantom.js url.

Here is my current hardcoded php:

```
$response = [];
exec('/usr/bin/phantomjs phantomjstest.js', $response);
$data = $response[19];
```

and phantom.js

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
console.log('The default user agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);
page.settings.userAgent = 'SpecialAgent111';
page.open('https://www.aa.com/travelInformation/flights/status/detail?search=AA|1698|2019,1,23&ref=search', function(status) {
if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('Unable to access network');
} else {
    var ua = page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.getElementById('aa-content-frame').innerHTML;
    });
    console.log(ua);
}
phantom.exit();
});
```

What I would like to do is change the php so that it passes 2 variables (from a form submit) to the javascript.  Something like:

PHP:

```
exec('/usr/bin/phantomjs phantomjstest.js?variable1=$forminput1&variable2=$forminput2', $response);
```

JS

```
page.open('https://www.aa.com/travelInformation/flights/status/detail?search=AA|variable1|variable2&ref=search', function(status) {
```

Or I can construct the entire URL in the php and send it along with the exec command.

Any ideas on either method, or some other way to get from here to there, are most appreciated.  Thanks.

---

Based on suggestions in comments, I have updated my PHP to contain:

```
exec("/usr/bin/phantomjs phantomjstest.js https://www.aa.com/travelInformation/flights/status/detail?search=AA|1698|2019,1,23&ref=search", $response);
```

and my JS to:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
console.log('The default user agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);
page.settings.userAgent = 'SpecialAgent111';

var system = require('system');
var args = require('system').args;
var address = system.args[0];
page.open(address, function (status) {

if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('Unable to access network');
} else {
    var ua = page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.getElementById('aa-content-frame').innerHTML;
    });
    console.log(ua);
}
phantom.exit();
});
```

But all I get back is a null response.  Any idea why the address is either not getting passed with PHP exec or not getting picked up and run by JS?

Thanks.

******  SOLUTION  ********

There were a couple of things that needed fixing, and I want to thank those that commented below, as well as others on SO that offered solutions to similar issues.

First, the JS did not like the & symbol in the URL.  I had to use @ in the passed argument instead and then replace it on the JS side.

Second, the JS did not like the pipe symbol in the URL so I had to escape them.

The finished PHP looks like:

```
exec("/usr/bin/phantomjs phantomjstest.js https://www.aa.com/travelInformation/flights/status/detail?search=AA\|$flight\|$date@ref=search", $response);
```

and the JS like:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
console.log('The default user agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);
page.settings.userAgent = 'SpecialAgent111';

var system = require('system');
var args = require('system').args;
var address = system.args[1];
var address = address.replace(/@/gi,"&");
page.open(address, function (status) {

if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('Unable to access network');
} else {
    var ua = page.evaluate(function() {
        return document.getElementById('aa-content-frame').innerHTML;
    });
    console.log(ua);
}
phantom.exit();
});
```

Again, my thanks to all!!!!

Comment: Assuming you know how to post form data to PHP etc - this might help in passing those vars to Phantomjs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16814997/phantomjs-pass-argument-to-the-js-file

Comment: I can post from data to php no problem.  After looking at the php exec manual and the link you posted, I still don't see how the form input gets passed from the php to the js.  Is the form input now the system arguments? Can you clarify for me? ....OOPS.... silly me, I think I may see your point.  Let me test.

Comment: I'm no expert on PhantomJS but I *think* that once you've got the form elements in the PHP script, you can then pass them to the exec like `exec("/usr/bin/phantomjs phantomjstest.js $arg1 $arg2")` (note the change from `'` to `"`) ... and you *should* be able to pick them up in your phantom.js file with `require('system').args` ... but I could be wrong.

Comment: Edited code based on comments, but still not working.  See above for update.

Comment: Solution posted above in edited question.  Thanks to all!!!

Comment: Post your solution in an answer, not in the question.

Comment: Ahhh... okay... I didn't think it was appropriate for me to answer my own question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

****** SOLUTION ********

There were a couple of things that needed fixing, and I want to thank those that commented below, as well as others on SO that offered solutions to similar issues.

First, the JS did not like the & symbol in the URL. I had to use @ in the passed argument instead and then replace it on the JS side.

Second, the JS did not like the pipe symbol in the URL so I had to escape them.

The finished PHP looks like:

```
exec("/usr/bin/phantomjs phantomjstest.js 
https://www.aa.com/travelInformation/flights/status/detail? 
search=AA\|$flight\|$date@ref=search", $response);
```

and the JS like:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
console.log('The default user agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);
page.settings.userAgent = 'SpecialAgent111';

var system = require('system');
var args = require('system').args;
var address = system.args[1];
var address = address.replace(/@/gi,"&");
page.open(address, function (status) {

if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('Unable to access network');
} else {
var ua = page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.getElementById('aa-content-frame').innerHTML;
});
console.log(ua);
}
phantom.exit();
});
```