# Meteor PhantomJS Dynamic URL parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, phantomjs

I've installed PhantomJS in my Meteor app using the instructions in the answer here: [Installing/Using Phantom.js with Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812163/installing-using-phantom-js-with-meteor)
but the method involved:

(private/phantomDriver.js)

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://github.com/', function (){
  console.log('Page Loaded');
  page.render('github.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

has a set URL... how can I pass parameters to the file to change the URL? e.g.

```
page.open(URL, etc...)
```

This:

```
var URL = newURL
spawn(phantomjs.path, ['assets/app/phantomDriver.js', URL]);
```

Logs

> "stdout: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: URL" to the console.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a variable to PhantomJS via exec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752882/passing-a-variable-to-phantomjs-via-exec) While the question might not match, the answer does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Artjom B.'s link didn't solve the problem (needed to use `spawn(phantomjs.path)` whereas `exec` expects a string I don't know of) - though it did lead me to the answer so, thanks!

Also made use of `require('system').args;` to access the arguments sent via `spawn`

Final code:

server.js:

```
spawn(phantomjs.path, ['assets/app/phantom_driver.js',URL]);
```

private/phantomDriver.js

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var args = require('system').args;
var URL = args[1]

page.open(URL, function(status) {
  console.log('Page loaded. Status: ' + status);
  page.render('github.png');
  phantom.exit();
})
```